# How to disable 'Smart rename' in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

In Visual Studio 2015 there is a feature to enable smart rename: [Renaming improvements](https://gooroo.io/GoorooTHINK/Article/16263/Visual-Studio-2015-IDE-Changes/17950#.Vb9Xb26qpHw). I would like to disalbe it but didn't found where. Does anyone knows where to do it?

Comment: What do you do to open the Rename popup?

Comment: @SergeyVlasov I don't have popup, but weird outline like [here](http://i.imgur.com/7fcfSam.png) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To hide the smart rename outline, you can install the [Plain Rename](https://vlasovstudio.com/plain-rename/) extension.

Comment: That's what I want it. Thanks! :D

Comment: Now please findout something for that ugly smart tags for while hovering html tags :( http://i.imgur.com/7mF4x3l.png

Comment: Hi Sergey, do you plan to update extension for Visual Studio 2019?

Comment: @mardok I've added support for VS 2019.